# Generate JSON with associations for API testing (Rails, Rspec, FactoryGirl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm new to Rails (4.0.0) and FactoryGirl (4.2.0) and am trying to generate JSON for a POST.  I'm using a custom strategy as suggested in the FactoryGirl documentation (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-strategies).

```
class JsonStrategy
  def initialize
    @strategy = FactoryGirl.strategy_by_name(:create).new
  end

  delegate :association, to: :@strategy

  def result(evaluation)
    @strategy.result(evaluation).to_json
  end
end
```

My problem is that I'd like the JSON to come back with a specified association.

Say I have two classes

```
class Votes
  belongs_to :people
end

class Person
  has_many :votes
end
```

Using FactoryGirl it would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
json = json(:person, :include => [:votes])
```

I'd like my JSON object to come back with somethings like this:

```
{
  'first_name': 'John',
  'last_name': 'Doe',
  'votes' : [
    {
      'name': 'Vote 1',
      'yea': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Vote 2',
      'yea': true
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this possible with FactoryGirl?  If not, is there a better way to accomplish this to test a JSON API with Rspec (2.14.1)?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind pointing to the FactoryGirl documentation on custom JSON strategy that you referred to?

Comment: Updated question with link to documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FactoryGirlJson](https://github.com/stream7/factory_girl_json) along with [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to generate *compound JSON*.

Nesting associations in API data is stinky – as complexity grows, the hierarchy will become denormalized and brittle. See: [Compound Documents](http://jsonapi.org/format/) (a.k.a. *sideloading*) in the JSON API. **ActiveModelSerializer** makes it easy to generate *compound documents*.

**FactoryGirlJson** is a very new project, and I am only now trying it myself. I found that upgrading to [FactoryGirlRails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) >= 4.2 before adding **FactoryGirlJson** to the **Gemfile** will solve some heartache with an old version of **FactoryGirlJson**.